# jq code to rewrite URLs where some values are arrays and some strings

Tags: json, bash, jq

In the following json I need to rewrite the `configURL` values and add `staging.` after(and only) `https://` - and ignore 'http://'. The thing is some of the values stored by `configURL` key are arrays. Original json looks like:

```
{
    "app1.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 2,
        "configURL": "https://companyX.com/app1/config.json"
    },
    "app2.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 2,
        "configURL": [
            "https://some-company.com/app2/config.json",
            "https://some-company.com/app2/config-resources.json",
            "http://some-company.com/app2/config-resources.json"
        ]
    },
    "app3.ini": {
        "content": "binaries",
        "scope": "deploy",
        "configURL": "https://staging.app4.com/app4/installs/binaries.ini",
        "resources": [
            "https://app4.com/resource",
            "https://app4.com/resource.bin",
            "https://app4.com/resource2.bin"
        ]
    },
    "app4.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 3,
        "configURL": [
            "https://different-company.com/app3/config.json",
            "https://different-company.com/app3/config-resources.json",
            "https://different-company.com/app3/config-binaries.json"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "https://different-company.com/resource",
            "https://different-company.com/resource.bin",
            "https://different-company.com/resource2.bin"
        ]
    }
}
```

The desired output is

```
{
    "app1.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 2,
        "configURL": "https://staging.companyX.com/app1/config.json"
    },
    "app2.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 2,
        "configURL": [
            "https://staging.some-company.com/app2/config.json",
            "https://staging.some-company.com/app2/config-resources.json",
        ]
    },
    "app3.ini": {
        "content": "binaries",
        "scope": "deploy",
        "configURL": "https://staging.staging.app4.com/app4/installs/binaries.ini",
        "resources": [
            "https://app4.com/resource",
            "https://app4.com/resource.bin",
            "https://app4.com/resource2.bin"
        ]
    },
    "app4.json": {
        "content": "app-config",
        "updates": 3,
        "configURL": [
            "https://staging.different-company.com/app3/config.json",
            "https://staging.different-company.com/app3/config-resources.json",
            "https://staging.different-company.com/app3/config-binaries.json"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "https://different-company.com/resource",
            "https://different-company.com/resource.bin",
            "https://different-company.com/resource2.bin"
        ]
    }
}
```

The following solution I managed to come up with works only when there aren't multiple URLs, but only one; I don't know how to add condition for, and modify each value in the array.

```
jq -r 'def camel:gsub( "https://"; "https://staging."); walk( if type=="object" and .configURL then (.configURL |= camel) else . end)' apps.json
```

Comment: You can ask what type something is, to branch on the result of that (whether it's an array or a single value). The attempt given in the question is a _very_ good start.

Comment: ...actually, you already _know_ you can do that, because you're using `type` in your existing code.

Comment: That said, why does your sample data have `configURL` but your sample code have `contentURL`?

Comment: Please specify explicitly how {"configURL": "http://"} should be handled - should the key in such cases be removed entirely? Also: why `gsub` as opposed to `sub`?  Would "^https://" be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking an object's `type` once -- just do it again:

```
jq -r '
  def camel:
    if type == "string" then
      gsub( "https://"; "https://staging.")
    else
      .[] |= camel
    end;

  walk( if type=="object" and .configURL then (.configURL |= camel) else . end)
' apps.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `(.[]? // .)` - it's essentially an if/else - the `?` catches the error and `// .` returns the original value.

```
$ jq -r '(.[].configURL | (.[]? // .))' apps.json
https://companyX.com/app1/config.json
https://some-company.com/app2/config.json
https://some-company.com/app2/config-resources.json
http://some-company.com/app2/config-resources.json
https://staging.app4.com/app4/installs/binaries.ini
https://different-company.com/app3/config.json
https://different-company.com/app3/config-resources.json
https://different-company.com/app3/config-binaries.json
```

You can then transform the results directly.

```
jq -r '(.[].configURL | (.[]? // .)) |= sub("^https://"; "https://staging.")'
```

Your `configURL` keys are all in the same place so you don't need recurse/walk but if you do you need to filter out potential nulls with `select()`

```
jq -r '(.. | .configURL? | select(.) | (.[]? // .)) |= sub("^https://"; "https://staging.")'
```